# NDB memcached show columns in output

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, memcached

We just started to work with **MySql-Cluster and ndb-memcached.** We created some tables which connects to ndb-memcached using ndbmemcache database and containers.

In the container table the value_columns are "Pref,Timestamp,Description". And in the reference table, these columns are exists.

It is works fine, but we are looking for a way to somehow **format the ndb-memcached** output.

**For example:**

---

*If we get prefix:1 key from ndb-memcached, the output is*

**get preferencies:1**

**VALUE preferencies:1 0 160**

**[Some associative array]  1463656103  [Some description]**

**END**

---

My question is
Is there any way to show the column names in the output of ndb-memcached query just like in MySql output?
E.g: The above VALUE could be something like:

---

**VALUE preferencies:1 0 160**

**Preferencies               Timestamp    Description**

**[Some associative array]  1463656103  [Some description]

END**

---

Or is there any way to query the columns and orders of columns from ndb-memcached without mysql query?

**May the ndb-memcached whole output format as an associative array?**

Best regards,